# What key is pressed in lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning, controller, keyboard

I want to read in my javascript controller what key is pressed in my lightning component. This is the lightning:input that I want to read.

```
    <lightning:input value="{!v.username}" aura:id="username" name="username" 
 onchange="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="input border sfdc_usernameinput sfdc lightFont loginWidth" label="{!$Label.c.B2B_Your_Email}" />
```

What do I have to do on the onchange to be able to read it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using an eventlistener on the `keydown`-event and reading the keycode. To use it on your input only, you need to register the eventlistener on that input field rather than the window-object (which is used in the example).

```javascript
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  alert("key: " + event.key + ", code: " + event.code);
}, true);
```

**Related documentation:**

- [MDN: KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a lightning component, you can access the event object and it's properties in both your controller and helper.

```
<ui:inputText value="{!v.val}"  keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" />
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
    onKeyUp: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.doKeyUp(component, event);
    }
})
```

**Helper.js**

```
({
    doKeyUp: function(component, event)
    {
        // access the event object in the helper using getParam() or getParams()
        console.log(event.getParam('keyCode'));
        console.log(event.getParams().keyCode);
    }
})
```

You should be able to access any properties available on the standard Javascript `Event` object using this method, more information about the `Event` object can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

I would also recommended taking a look at the Javascript API documentation found in the Aura Reference App which you can find by navigating to the following URL:

https://*`yourdomain`*.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app#reference?topic=api:Event

Comment: Just to add on in the answer if someone still struggling, please use `event.keyCode`,